# Random Substitution Cipher in Java

Tags: java, encryption

Im currently creating code to cipher text in Java using predefined characters. The code first ciphers the text and prints it out, it then deciphers it and prints out the original sentence. When I print out letters alone it works but it doesn't work when I combine a letter with a space key. The error I get is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27
>
> at cipher.cipher.decrypt(cipher.java:70)
>
> at cipher.cipher.main(cipher.java:24)

```
public static final int ASCII_SUB = 96;
public static final int ASCII_SUB_FOR_SPACE = 32;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter the text that you would like to cipher:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cipher = input.nextLine();
    input.close();
    
    int length = cipher.length();
    
    char encryption[] = createCipher();
    String cipheredText = encrypt(encryption, cipher, length);
    
    System.out.println("The encrypted version of your sentence is: " + cipheredText);
    char[] encryptedCharacters = cipheredText.toCharArray();
    String original = decrypt(encryption, encryptedCharacters, length);
    
    System.out.println("Your original sentence was: " + original);
}

public static char[] createCipher(){
    
    char[] encryption = {'p', 'u', 'y', 'k', 'h', 'q', 'j', 'l',
            'i', 'd', 'v', 'b', ' ', 'o', 'c', 'f', 'r', 'e', 't', 'x',
            'a', 'n', 'z', 'm', 'g', 'w', 's' };
    
    return encryption;
}


public static String encrypt(char[] encryption, String cipher, int length){
    
    String lowercaseCipher = cipher.toLowerCase();
    char[] characterArray = lowercaseCipher.toCharArray();
    
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if(characterArray[i] == ' '){
            characterArray[i] = (char) (characterArray[i] - ASCII_SUB_FOR_SPACE);
        }
        else{
            characterArray[i] = (char) (characterArray[i] - ASCII_SUB);
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        characterArray[i] = encryption[characterArray[i]];
    }
    
    String cipheredText = new String(characterArray);
    return cipheredText;
}


public static String decrypt(char[] encryption, char[] encryptedCharacters, int length){
    
    int p = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int[] deciphered = new int[length];
    
    do {
        if(encryption[i] == encryptedCharacters[p]){
            deciphered[w] = i;
            i = 0;
            w++;
            p++;
            }
    i++;
    }while(p<length);
    
    char[] finishedSentence = new char[length];
    for(int x = 0;x<length;x++){
        if(deciphered[x] == 0){
            finishedSentence[x] = (char) (deciphered[x] + ASCII_SUB_FOR_SPACE);
        }
        else{
            finishedSentence[x] = (char) (deciphered[x] + ASCII_SUB);
        }
    }   
        
    
    String deCipheredText = new String(finishedSentence);
    
    return deCipheredText;
}
```

line 70 is: if(encryption[i] == encryptedCharacters[p]){

p.s. apologies for the poor variable names but I haven't had time to fix them yet.

Comment: could you point out which line is 70 so that we can identify the buggy line? Also, have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code just there to show line 70. I'm using eclipse as a compiler and can't see any option to step line by line?

Comment: I don't know much about eclipse, but in my experience with debugging, you need to set breakpoint to start. Then you can step through. Breakpoints should be set-able by clicking on line numbers. I recommend one at the beginning of your encrypt and decrypt methods so you can see how it encrypts and attempts to decrypt the space char.

Comment: Not sure how to mark the question as answered, should I just delete it? but figured out that the problem was with the post-increment at line 70. if the space wasn't first, i would always start off at 1 instead of 0, so I put the post increment into an else loop. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Best solution for marking the question is to **Answer your own question** in the answer box and mark it as accepted with the green check

Answer (score 0):

With the if statement at line 70. "i" will always start off at 1 instead of 0, put the post increment into an else loop and it fixes this.